# Non-public storages: Wrong publicUrl in FE & BE?

Tags: typo3, fal, typo3-11.x

Normally (til TYPO3 v10) the output of files that are stored in non-public storages, is done via [eID fileDump](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/ExamplesFileFolder.html?highlight=file%20reference#dumping-a-file-via-eid-script).

Now, with TYPO3 v11, I get URIs like `/storage/_processed_/d/4/csm_IMG_1186_520147cc3c.jpg` for the publicUrl of the files - instead of an eID link.

Is it a bug or a faulty configuration?

Comment: Maybe that is related to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/93024? There is a patch https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/67333 merged already which you can apply. It'll be in the next v11/v10 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the "Is publicly available?" checkbox of the FileStorage was enabled. For non-public folders, this has of course to be disabled.

[image]